# What is the meaning of non fiction stories w.r.t kids?

Tags: non-fiction

http://www.english-for-students.com/Non-Fiction-Short-Stories.html

Non fiction means based on reality. So, how do the stories listed there fit in this category?

If I wish to write a non fiction story for kids, what am I supposed to write? I need an example distinguishing fiction story and a non fiction story for "kids".

Comment: You have plenty of examples in the link. What's confusing you? A non-fiction story is one which happened — e.g., biographies of famous people which are written for kids. Fiction didn't happen. Throw a Lego in the children's section of any bookstore and you'll hit a fiction book for kids. (or a kid. So be careful when throwing.)

Comment: Fiction = made up; non-fiction = has actually happened in our world. Look at these Wikipedia articles, they explain it in more detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiction and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fiction If you still have difficulties, read about fiction and non-fiction **in your native tongue**. I think you are confused because your English is not good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a quick glance at your link and I don't consider those stories non-fiction either.

As for what I would consider non-fiction for kids, I'll use the example of a book I bought for my nephew. It was a biography of Pele (since my nephew plays soccer). It was written for children and is definitely non-fiction.

Off the top of my head, other ideas might be the story of a lost dog finding its way home or perhaps a bit of history. It's more about the way the story is told, in these cases, that make it for kids. As long as the subject matter is age-appropriate (however you define that), you can have a wide range. Base it in reality and it is non-fiction.